# Error in tpl file or php version is wrong

Tags: cs-cart

I try to find similar problem like mine but seems no luck. I have cs-cart multivendor with php7.1 tested with normal theme work fine but when i install new theme site working until i login on admin panel. So that means after my login on admin panel site goes in white screen. I try to figure and i see in my theme folder index.tpl file always getting empty. So to site to work again I have to replace the index.tpl file again. Here is the code of the index.tpl file. Can u please tell me if there is some error in file who doing site to go down? Thank you!

> {capture name="page_title"} {hook name="index:title"} {if
>   $page_title}
>       {$page_title} {else}
>       {if $language_direction == "rtl"}
>           {foreach from=$breadcrumbs|@array_reverse item=i name="bkt"}
>               {if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.last}{if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.last && !$smarty.foreach.bkt.first} ::
>   {/if}{$i.title|strip_tags}{/if}
>           {/foreach}
>       {else}
>           {foreach from=$breadcrumbs item=i name="bkt"}
>               {if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.first}{$i.title|strip_tags}{if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.last} :: {/if}{/if}
>           {/foreach}
>       {/if}
>       {if !$skip_page_title && $location_data.title}{if $breadcrumbs|count > 1} - {/if}{$location_data.title}{/if} {/if}
>   {/hook} {/capture} {$smarty.capture.page_title|strip|trim
>   nofilter} {include file="meta.tpl"} {hook name="index:links"}
>        {/hook} {include file="common/styles.tpl" include_dropdown=true} {if "DEVELOPMENT"|defined && $smarty.const.DEVELOPMENT == true}
>    window.jsErrors = [];
>   window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
>       var verboseMessage = message;
>       if (source) {
>           verboseMessage = source + '@' + lineno + ':' + colno + "\n\n" + message;
>       }
>
> ```
> console.error(verboseMessage);
>
> if (error && error.stack) {
>     console.log(error.stack);
> }
>
> document.write('<pre data-ca-debug="1" style="border: 2px solid red; margin: 2px;">'
>     + verboseMessage + "\n\n"
>     + (error && error.stack ? error.stack : '')
>     + '</pre>'
> ); }; </script> <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.1.9/es5-shim.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
> ```
>
> {/if} {hook name="index:head_scripts"}{/hook}
>
> {hook name="index:body"}
>           {if $runtime.customization_mode.design}
>               {include file="common/toolbar.tpl" title=**("on_site_template_editing")
>   href="customization.disable_mode?type=design"}
>           {/if}
>           {if $runtime.customization_mode.live_editor}
>               {include file="common/toolbar.tpl" title=**("on_site_live_editing")
>   href="customization.disable_mode?type=live_editor"}
>           {/if}
>           {if "THEMES_PANEL"|defined && !$runtime.customization_mode.live_editor}
>               {include file="demo_theme_selector.tpl"}
>           {/if}
>
> ```
>     <div class="ty-tygh {if $runtime.customization_mode.theme_editor}te-mode{/if} {if
> ```
>
> $runtime.customization_mode.live_editor ||
>   $runtime.customization_mode.design ||
>   $smarty.const.THEMES_PANEL}ty-top-panel-padding{/if}"
>   id="tygh_container">
>
> ```
>     {include file="common/loading_box.tpl"}
>     {include file="common/notification.tpl"}
>
>     <div class="ty-helper-container" id="tygh_main_container">
>         {hook name="index:content"}
>             {hook name="index:et_content"}{/hook}
>         {/hook}
>     <!--tygh_main_container--></div>
>
>     {hook name="index:footer"}{/hook}
>     <!--tygh_container--></div>
>
>     {include file="common/scripts.tpl"}
>
>     {if $runtime.customization_mode.design}
>         {include file="backend:common/template_editor.tpl"}
>     {/if}
>     {if $runtime.customization_mode.theme_editor}
>         {include file="backend:common/theme_editor.tpl"}
>     {/if}
> {/hook} </body>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your license for the theme you are using